# WordPress Category List Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I'm looking to build a list of posts from a specific category. I can retrieve them with the loop I've created but it's not displaying them the way I need them to.  I want to run the loop and stack all the post titles in one div (if that makes sense).

I have two columns in my bootstrap layout.  The first column displays a youtube video and the second column has the name of the video.  Since its looping, the videos stack up and the titles stack up (like so)...

[image]

This isn't what I want.  I want something like this

[image]

I also need to figure out a way to add a class to the first video and hide the rest.  But that's a different issue.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
<div class="videosSection">
    <div class="callout">
        <h1>Getting Started Videos</h1>
    </div>
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'videos_post',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $videos_loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($videos_loop->have_posts()) : while ($videos_loop->have_posts()) : $videos_loop->the_post();
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videos_fields', true); ?>


        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 videosContainer <?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>">
            <div class="videoPlayerContainer">
                <iframe width="100%" height="315"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>"
                        frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                        allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="videoLinks">
                <p class="<?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>"><?php echo $meta['VideoTitle']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Post your code so we can assist.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the videos section code

Comment: You need a conditional statement for outputting the "<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">" because you only want to output this once.  Using a loop counter and checking if it's the last and first video in the loop will acheive this.  I'll write some code now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a conditional statement for outputting the title column divs because you only want to output this div column once. Using a loop counter and checking if it's the last and first video in the loop will achieve this.  I haven't test this so let me know if there's any issues and I'll see if I can setup a test scenario to try it.

```
if ($videos_loop->have_posts()) : 
    for ( $x = 1; $x <= $videos_loop->post_count; $x++ ) :
    $videos_loop->the_post();
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videos_fields', true); 

?>


    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 videosContainer <?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>">
        <div class="videoPlayerContainer">
            <iframe width="100%" height="315"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>"
                    frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if( $x == 1 ) : ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="videoLinks">
            <p class="<?php echo $meta['VideoLink']; ?>"><?php echo $meta['VideoTitle']; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( $x == $videos_loop->post_count) : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>


<?php 
    endfor;

endif;
```

Comment: The only thing it seems to be doing is returning the first video and first title. There's also error  here at the end 

                                <?php
                            endfor;

                            endif; ?>

Comment: Missed out the colon on the for loop.  Should compile now, hard for me to test this but do you understand the idea behind how you achieve it?

Comment: this is kinda working now.  I'm only seeing one video in the left hand column ( I need all videos so I can hide/Show based on jquery) and the right hand column is missing one of the titles, and is listing the videos.